# Flutter Freezed Method not found

Tags: flutter, code-generation, freezed

I'm using `Freezed` to generate data-class on my flutter project.

I did everything exactly like mentioned in the [package readme](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed):

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'access_token.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class AccessToken with _$AccessToken {
  @JsonSerializable()
  const factory AccessToken(
    @JsonKey(name: 'access_token') String accessToken,
    @JsonKey(name: 'refresh_token') String refreshToken,
  ) = _AccessToken;

  factory AccessToken.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) =>
      _$AccessTokenFromJson(json);
}
```

The build completes successfully.

When I run the app I'm getting:

> lib/services/models/access_token.freezed.dart:118:7: Error: Method not
> found: '_$$_AccessTokenFromJson'.
> _$$*AccessTokenFromJson(json);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lib/services/models/access_token.freezed.dart:157:12: Error: The
> method '*$$*AccessTokenToJson' isn't defined for the class
> '*$_AccessToken'.
>
> - '_$*AccessToken' is from 'package:tenant_app/services/models/access_token.dart'
>   ('lib/services/models/access_token.dart'). Try correcting the name to
>   the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
>   '*$$_AccessTokenToJson'.
>   return _$$_AccessTokenToJson(

Why `Freezed` didn't generate that function correctly? What am I missing?

Comment: Problem solved. I accidentally forgot to add the `json_annotation` and `json_serializable` to my project dependences.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add the following part:

```
part 'access_token.g.dart';
```

And you don't need the following:

```
@JsonSerializable()
```

And make sure you run (using `build` or `watch` below):

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

I took your example and **successfully** generated everything using:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'access_token.freezed.dart';
part 'access_token.g.dart';

@freezed
class AccessToken with _$AccessToken {
  const factory AccessToken(
    @JsonKey(name: 'access_token') String accessToken,
    @JsonKey(name: 'refresh_token') String refreshToken,
  ) = _AccessToken;

  factory AccessToken.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => _$AccessTokenFromJson(json);
}
```

Using `freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0`, `freezed: ^2.1.0+1`, `build_runner: ^2.2.0,` `json_annotation: ^4.6.0`, `json_serializable: ^6.3.1`
Make sure to check that those are included (according to OP in comment to this answer, packages was missing).

Generated .g.dart file:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'access_token.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

_$_AccessToken _$$_AccessTokenFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    _$_AccessToken(
      json['access_token'] as String,
      json['refresh_token'] as String,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$$_AccessTokenToJson(_$_AccessToken instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'access_token': instance.accessToken,
      'refresh_token': instance.refreshToken,
    };
```

Comment: I accidentally forgot to add the json_annotation and json_serializable to my project dependences. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with **flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs**

Answer (score 0):

is it null safety...? if yes use ?  in all fields

and also missed .g.dart'; path

i will give an example

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
part 'comments.model.freezed.dart';
part 'comments.model.g.dart';        // missing

@freezed
@immutable
class CommentsModel with _$CommentsModel {
  const CommentsModel._();
  const factory CommentsModel({
    int? id,
    @JsonKey(name: 'x_post_id') int? xPostId,
    @JsonKey(name: 'x_user_id') int? xUserId,
    @JsonKey(name: 'x_body') String? xBody,
    @JsonKey(name: 'comment_likes_count') int? commentLikesCount,
    @JsonKey(name: 'comment_like_by_user_count') int? commentLikeByUserCount,
    @JsonKey(name: 'created_at') DateTime? createdAt,
    @JsonKey(name: 'updated_at') DateTime? updatedAt,
  }) = _CommentsModel;

  factory CommentsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CommentsModelFromJson(json);
}
```

to run build_runner use this also

> flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs

Comment: The problem is that it does not generate the `.g.dart` file. So I removed it.

Comment: ? in all fields

Comment: then run this flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs

Comment: add this 'access_token.g.dart';

Comment: Does it generates the `.g.dart` file for you?

Comment: Null safety have nothing to do with it.

Comment: there is a possibility of a accessToken getting null ,  it's datatype is String not String? so i mention it to handle that issue too

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to add:

```dart
part 'access_token.g.dart';
```

This aspect is mentioned in the official [package page](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed), on pub.dev.

```dart
// This file is "main.dart"
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

// required: associates our `main.dart` with the code generated by Freezed
part 'main.freezed.dart';
// optional: Since our Person class is serializable, we must add this line.
// But if Person was not serializable, we could skip it.
part 'main.g.dart';

@freezed
class Person with _$Person {
  const factory Person({
    required String firstName,
    required String lastName,
    required int age,
  }) = _Person;

  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json)
      => _$PersonFromJson(json);
}
```